# ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES ajax code for REAL-TIME CLOCK

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a real-time clock that updates every second. When I run it locally I see no errors. However when I uploaded it to my web host I saw a lot of error messages in the console every time the AJAX code runs.

I think that's the reason why web host suspended my site, telling that my site has performed too many requests.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#time').load('timewithdate.php')
  }, 1000);

  setInterval(function(){
    $('#time2').load('time.php')
   }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: What if i remove the second time request? Will there be an error?

Comment: Yes, but it would just take longer. You should not be polling the server repeatedly partly because you'll run in to the same problem eventually, and partly because it's more effective to make a countdown timer on the client side without needing to waste server resources.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you have effectively [DDOS'd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) your own server with 2 requests every second * number of concurrent clients. I would strongly suggest you remove these AJAX requests and perform the countdown on the client side.

If you're trying to keep the clocks in sync with server time, get the time from the server when the page loads, then add seconds to it on the client side. Do not use AJAX for this, and do not use AJAX polling in future. It's an anti-pattern.

Comment: _perform the countdown on the server side_ -> Surely, you meant "on the client side"

Comment: Okay, how would I perform it on the server side, I'm using PHP for that. I want to update the time automatically every second. Thank you.

Comment: You don't; that's the entire point. Do it on the client. If you absolutely *have* to keep the client/server time in sync then research websockets, but this will be a paradigm shift in terms of how the logic on your site needs to be structured.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.  Your code is a certain way to kill a server: it's making 2 calls to the server every second for each client (read more about [DDOS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/what-is-a-ddos-attack/)).  There is no need to make a server call, just use javascript to get the current time and format it the way you want. You can have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  setInterval(function() {
    let curTime = new Date();
    let date = curTime.toLocaleDateString();
    let time = curTime.toLocaleTimeString();
    $('#time').text(date + " " + time);
    $('#time2').text(time);
  }, 1000);
})
```